# Proof of Schwarz Inequality using Bra-ket notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, vectors

I'm trying to prove Schwarz Inequality, where
$$\mid\left\langle \alpha | \beta \right\rangle\mid^2 \leq \left\langle \alpha | \alpha\right\rangle \left\langle \beta| \beta\right\rangle $$

So I defined $
\left|Z\right\rangle = \left|V\right\rangle - 
\frac{\left\langle \ W| \ V\right\rangle }{\mid W\mid^2}\left|W\right\rangle$ and then 
$$\left\langle Z | Z \right\rangle=\left\langle V | V \right\rangle - \frac{\left\langle \ W| \ V\right\rangle }{\mid W\mid^2}\left\langle \ V| \ W\right\rangle - \frac{\left\langle \ W| \ V\right\rangle^* }{\mid W\mid^2}\left\langle \ W| \ V\right\rangle + \frac{\mid\left\langle W | V \right\rangle\mid^2 \left\langle W | W \right\rangle}{\mid W \mid ^4} \geq 0  $$

What I did next was to take $\left\langle W | V \right\rangle^*=\left\langle V | W \right\rangle$ and I ended up with

$$\left\langle V | V \right\rangle - \frac{\left\langle \ W| \ V\right\rangle \left\langle \ V| \ W\right\rangle}{\mid W\mid^2} - \frac{\left\langle \ V| \ W\right\rangle \left\langle \ W| \ V\right\rangle}{\mid W\mid^2} + \frac{\left\langle V | W \right\rangle \left\langle W | V \right\rangle \left\langle W | W \right\rangle}{\mid W \mid ^4} \geq 0 $$

And I got stuck there, how should I follow? I can't find anywhere how to proceed from this last line, as every proof I see they go from this last line straight to the result,and it's not obvious for me, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using Dirac Bra-ket notation doesn't mean that your question is about Physics. I suggest its migration to Math SE.

Comment: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/dirac-notation-schwarz-inequality-proof.758832/ might save you a move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remember that $\langle W|W\rangle=|W|^2$. Then the 4th term cancels the 3rd one. Multiplying the resulting inequality on $\langle W|W\rangle$ you get the answer.

Comment: ah you beat me to it...